# Laravel foreign key relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got a strange problem.

I've a users table and a company table. A User belongsTo a company and a company hasMany users.

Both primary keys of the table are id.

In the laravel documentation I read the following:

> Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a
>   value matching the id column of the parent.

I've got this in my `CompanyModel`:

```
protected $table = 'company';

public function users()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(UserModel::class);
   }
```

When I try this:

```
$users = CompanyModel::find(1)->users;
dd($users);
```

It's not working. When I add a foreign key in my relation it works!?:

```
protected $table = 'company';

public function users()
  {
     return $this->hasMany(UserModel::class, 'id');
  }
```

This is strange right? What on earth am I doing wrong.

--EDIT--

In my `users` table I've got a `company_id` column!

Comment: Documentation suggests that you have a company_id column in users table. The result you get by adding 'id' is probably wrong.

Comment: I've got a company_id column in my users table!

Comment: I think you should have a company_model_id column in users table or add "company_id" in your relation instead of "id" as the foreign key.

Comment: you have also the belongsTo method in User model right?

Comment: Is it working $users = CompanyModel::find(1)->with('users');

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would suggest you rename your Model from `CompanyModel`to `Company` and from `UserModel` to `User`.

Then ensure you have `company_id` in your `users` table. And in your `users` migration file connect the `users` table with the `companies` table as such:

```
    $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Don't forget to refresh your database.

Then in your models, define the relationships as such:

```
    // User model
    // Laravel will automatically identify and use the `company_id` field in your reference
    public function company(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    // Company model
    public function users(){
       return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

You can then fetch your records in your controller as such:

```
    $user = User::find(1);

    $user_company = $user->company; // This might not be necessary in your controller, you can do it in your view

    dd($users, $user_company);
```